# Can applying for US Global Entry reduce the frequency with which I am stopped at border control?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

I was inspired to ask as a follow-up to this question:
[Denied US Entry in 2012. Is this on my PERMANENT record?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/131603/denied-us-entry-in-2012-is-this-on-my-permanent-record)

If you are regularly being taken for secondary inspections at the US border, will applying to enrol for the US Global Entry program help to resolve these types of issues? Or would the applicant likely to just be rejected on the same basis for which they are regularly getting pulled aside?

Comment: IF you’re approved for Global Entry, you are good to go. However Global Entry to my knowledge is for checking your profile, not fixing flags on your profile. For that reason I expect you will simply be denied by Global Entry and the saga continues. The UK on the other hand [has a mechanism for removing flags which should be removed](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/96671/can-a-uk-border-immigration-officer-remove-a-stop-indicator-flag).

Comment: Also, be aware that if you apply for Global Entry and are denied, your application fee is **not** refundable.